# Number puzzles - What goes instead of "?"

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction

One of my friends went to an interview and got this question : "What goes in the `?` circle?"

We tried for hours to find out, but couldn't.
I found a possible solution to be : if we mark the numbers from the inner circle with a,b,c,d etc and those from the outer circle with A,B,C,D etc then a+b modulo N = A + B modulo N, where N the outside number. But where the `?` is, 1+8 = 4+5 so the rule fails here

[image]

Comment: An *interview*? Like a job interview?!

Comment: Yeah, a job interview. There were over 400 students and they give 9 paper with this kind of puzzles.

Comment: That's absolutely absurd.

Comment: Why do you think that?

Comment: Why do I think interviewers shouldn't be using puzzle games to select candidates? Because unless you're going into the puzzle game industry it's no better than random selection.

Comment: I tend to disagree with you, because nowadays if you have a problem, you can easily Google it, you don't think anymore, and most of the time you end up not knowing what your code does. But in Computer science field it is very important to "think twice and write once", so solving this kind of puzzles can prove that you know how to use your logical skills

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57601/discussion-between-veedrac-and-snukies).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pretty simple to be honest,

> The sum the small circle values minus the bigger circle values where the outer values like crosses: $(4+2)-(3+1)=2$

or

[image]

> sum(reds) - sum(blues)

So the answer will be;

> $(4+5)-(1+8)=0$

Comment: Well, you ninja'd me :)

Comment: @JonathanAllan next time :)

Comment: I honestly never thought of that... thought we had somehow to link them to form the outer number.

Comment: @SnuKies Someone even wrote `4+5=9` and `1+8=9` at the bottom right! :)

Comment: @JonathanAllan haha did not notice that :)

Comment: @JonathanAllan that was me :D But just to show a friend my modulo solution.

Comment: Perhaps worth pointing out as well: it follows from this that the OP's find that A+B=a-b mod N is correct and would apply to all numbers following the same pattern, it's just not specific enough to find the answer.